# How do I set the session language in MATE on Debian?

Tags: debian, language, mate

I'm using the default install from the Debian-8-MATE live DVD. In lightdm there is a selection for the language, but my user session never changes the language (system language should stay as it is). The locales are installed and I generated them (whatever that means) with dpkg-reconfigure locales.

How do I configure the language for my user session, if lightdm's selection doesn't do it? I tried exporting LANG in .bashrc, but that didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Debian Bug report logs - #784065
language settings not properly applied in X session:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=784065

Debian Bug report logs - #765077
lightdm-gtk-greeter: Language selection is broken (again):

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=765077

Comment: If the links break or are unavailable, this post would contain no useful information.  Super User's purpose is to build a knowledgebase of questions and answers rather than a collection of links to answers elsewhere.  Please include the essential information within the answer and use the links for attribution and further reading.  These links are lengthy discussions and the relevant information is not obvious.

Comment: Time waste, it isn’t working.